# Uniform convergence when no limit function is specified.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

What does it mean when someone asks you to show that a series of functions converges uniformly without specifying to what function? In the past when I've delt with uniform convergence, I've always been asked to show that a sequence converges uniformly to a given function. But what does the question mean when no limit-function is specified?

For example: "Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n f_n(x)$ converges uniformly". What does this mean? What am I asked to do in such cases?

Comment: Assuming that $f_n$ is a sequence of real-valued functions, it suffices to show that $\sum a_nf_n$ is uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: @Math1000, thanks. What does it mean that $\sum a_n f_n$ is uniformly cauchy?

Comment: If $F_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_nf_n$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n,m\geqslant N$ implies $|F_n(x)-F_m(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If a sequence of functions converges uniformly to a function, then it also converges pointwise to that function. So you can find the pointwise limit, then check that it converges uniformly to that limit.

Comment: So I when someone says "Show uniform convergence", it implies that I shall check to convergence to something? In other words, I must first deduce what the limit function is, then check that the partial sums converge uniformly to this limit?

Comment: @MariusJonsson Yes.

Comment: if you think it is a good idea to add this detail to your reply, then I shall accept it as the answer :)

Comment: @MariusJonsson: It is not necessary to find the pointwise limit in order to prove uniform convergence. It's just one possible way $-$ and not the easiest, in general. For instance, it is often easier to show that the functions $a_nf_n$ converge uniformly to zero fast enough.

Comment: @TonyK Although this may be off-topic, can you point me at a relevant theorem? Thanks.

Comment: @MariusJonsson: I don't know where to find such a thing on the internet, but here's an example: if $|a_nf_n(x)| < 2^{-n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in S$, then $\sum a_nf_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$. You should try to prove this yourself. (In fact, you can replace $2^{-n}$ in this mini-theorem by the elements of any convergent series, such as $1/n^2$.)

Comment: @TonyK, This is the Weierstrass M-test, isnt it?

Comment: So it is! (Did you know about this test before you posted your question?)

Comment: Yes, I learnt it many years ago. I just came to remember it now. This is so off-topic. I am sorry.